# How to set a RegExp to have a real matching judgement?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I would like to set a RegExp to have a matching judgement with String. I tried to use pattern.test(str), but if pattern is a part of string it will be true. It isn't what i want.

For example, I set my pattern is "/[a-z]/" and str is "abc123", it will be true by pattern.test(str). My prefer result is false, because the str contains "123", not every character is a-z. How can I do that? Thank you!

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class regexp extends Sprite{
        var pattern:RegExp=/[a-z]/;
        var str:String="abc123";

        public function regexp() {
            trace(pattern.test(str));
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var pattern:RegExp=/^[a-z]+?$/;
```

Comment: What is the function of the non-greedy + in this regex? Why not just +?